(Solaris) Ram CPU monitoring script is grabbing incorrect cpu ram utilization values

host=$(hostname)
email="abc.@xyz.com"  # Change to your desired email
subject="Attention!!! Health check Failed on $host"
echo $(date)

# CPU use threshold
cpu_threshold=0

# Memory idle threshold
mem_threshold=0

#--- CPU
cpu_usage () {
    # Get CPU idle percentage
    cpu_idle=$(prstat -Z 1 1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $8}' | tr -d '%')
    
    # Check if cpu_idle is a valid number
    if ! [[ "$cpu_idle" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Error: Invalid CPU idle value: $cpu_idle"
        cpu_use=0
    else
        cpu_use=$((100 - cpu_idle))
    fi

    cpu_flag=0
    echo "CPU utilization: $cpu_use%"
    if [ "$cpu_use" -gt "$cpu_threshold" ]; then
        echo "CPU warning!!!"
        cpu_flag=1
    else
        echo "CPU ok!!!"
    fi
}

#--- Memory
mem_usage () {
    mem_total=$(kstat -m | grep "physmem" | awk '{print $2}')  # Total memory in bytes
    mem_free=$(kstat -m | grep "freemem" | awk '{print $2}')   # Free memory in bytes

    if [[ -z "$mem_total" || "$mem_total" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Failed to retrieve total memory."
        mem_total=0
        mem_free=0
    fi

    # Convert bytes to GB
    mem_total_gb=$((mem_total / 1024 / 1024))
    mem_free_gb=$((mem_free / 1024 / 1024))

    echo "Total memory: $mem_total_gb GB"
    echo "Free memory: $mem_free_gb GB"

    if [ "$mem_total" -gt 0 ]; then
        per_mem=$(( ((mem_total - mem_free)) * 100 / mem_total ))
    else
        per_mem=0
    fi

    echo "Memory space remaining: $mem_free_gb GB"
    mem_flag=0
    if [ "$per_mem" -gt "$mem_threshold" ]; then
        echo "Memory warning!!!"
        mem_flag=1
    else
        echo "Memory ok!!!"
    fi
}

out() {
    if [ "$cpu_flag" -eq 1 ] && [ "$mem_flag" -eq 1 ]; then 
        printf "
Hello Team,

Please check RAM and CPU utilization on $host.
Current RAM Percentage: $per_mem%%
Current CPU Percentage: $cpu_use%%

Thanks " > /tmp/health.txt
    elif [ "$cpu_flag" -eq 1 ]; then 
        printf "
Hello Team,

Please check CPU utilization on $host.
Current CPU Percentage: $cpu_use%%

Thanks " > /tmp/health.txt
    elif [ "$mem_flag" -eq 1 ]; then 
        printf "
Hello Team,

Please check RAM utilization on $host.
Current RAM Percentage: $per_mem%%

Thanks " > /tmp/health.txt
    fi
}

mail() {
    if [ "$cpu_flag" -eq 1 ] || [ "$mem_flag" -eq 1 ]; then
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -t <<EOF
Subject: $subject
From: donotreply@example.com
To: $email

$(cat /tmp/health.txt)
EOF
    fi
}

# Execute functions
cpu_usage
mem_usage
out
mail

It gives the following output. Despite using kstat, it throws this error. What am I doing wrong here?
Fri Oct 11 06:51:21 CDT 2024
Error: Invalid CPU idle value: 17:25:22
CPU utilization: 0%
CPU ok!!!
Usage:
kstat [ -qlp ] [ -T d|u ] [ -c class ]
      [ -m module ] [ -i instance ] [ -n name ] [ -s statistic ]
      [ interval [ count ] ]
kstat [ -qlp ] [ -T d|u ] [ -c class ]
      [ module:instance:name:statistic ... ]
      [ interval [ count ] ]
Usage:
kstat [ -qlp ] [ -T d|u ] [ -c class ]
      [ -m module ] [ -i instance ] [ -n name ] [ -s statistic ]
      [ interval [ count ] ]
kstat [ -qlp ] [ -T d|u ] [ -c class ]
      [ module:instance:name:statistic ... ]
      [ interval [ count ] ]
Failed to retrieve total memory.
Total memory: 0 GB
Free memory: 0 GB
Memory space remaining: 0 GB
Memory ok!!!

The CPU utilization is getting grabbed correctly now, only the memory usage is not reported correctly. I am not sure which module to use with kstat command, so I used prtconf as well but that didn't capture it either.

Which part is giving the error? Presumably, you have tried debugging it, right? You have tried adding echo statements in different parts of the script to focus in on the specific part that fails? Please [edit] your question and include this. You are apparently passing a time (17:25:22) to something expecting a valid "CPU idle value". And you are using this kstat thing wrong. The error message suggests that -m needs a module.

In line the CPU is 9th parameter:
   cpu_idle=$(prstat -Z 1 1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $9}' | tr -d '%')

But this command will not give you the IDLE time. will give you CPU time of first process in the list. Better use command:
vmstat 1 2|nawk 'NR==4 {print $NF}'

kstat commands can be rewritten on this way:
mem_total=$(kstat |  nawk '/physmem/ {print $2}')
mem_free=$(kstat | nawk '/freemem/ {print $2}') 

P.S. Use nawk , the original Solaris awk have some specifics you do not want to fight with
